# Gondor is complaining that it could not import settings

Tags: django

I was trying to create a new application on Gondor, and I was getting this error:

```
Error: Could not import settings 'dt.conf.production' (Is it on sys.path?): No module named dt.conf.production.
```

I confirmed that the file exists, however, and even did "import production from dt.conf" in a shell successfully.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There were a pair of issues here. Here they are in order of increasing embarrassment.

First, make sure you have the parent directory added to sys.path. Your wsgi.py file should look like this:

```
import os
import sys

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "dt.conf.production")

# Add parent dir to path
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(
    os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
    os.pardir)))

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

Second, and this is the one that killed me, remember that when you call gondor deploy, it's going to take whatever is in your repository. So, in my case, I had to do

```
git add conf
git commit
```

and then do

```
gondor deploy primary master
```

Hope it helps!